# Is there a way give a JSlider, that is disabled for user input, in Java normal visibility?

Tags: java, swing

I want to use a JSlider to display my data, and as such I don't want users to be able to move them as then it would no longer display the correct value. At the moment I'm disabling the JSlider so the user can't move the slider, but doing that makes the visibility of the slider really poor.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against showing an enabled, but inspirational slider, as it is against typical UI conventions and will likely confuse the users.

Nonetheless, if you really want to do it: The default `JSlider` is either enabled or not, so you cannot do what you want directly. A workaround would be to have it enabled and add an `ActionListener` to it. This would be called once the user changes the value. In this ActionListener, you could just reset the value of the slider to its original value, so the slider would snap back. Again, this is very atypical behaviour of UI elements and might confuse users.

In the end, I would suggest coming up with your own component that displays a bar or other slider-like element to visualize your values, but which do not accept any user input.